# Download, Unzip, and Parse a file in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, bing-api

I'm working with the very frustrating Bing Ads Api (SOAP) and while I've successfully executed the majority of SOAP requests I need, the last one is giving me trouble.

The team there tells me that to get an ad campaigns stats (clicks, impressions, conversions, etc.) I need to Request a report be generated (pass it the parameters), then take the reportID from the response and "poll" the report with another SOAP request, which yields a download URL for a zip file.

I've successfully done all the above and the download URL (which is only good for 5mins) looks like this:

`https://download.api.bingads.microsoft.com/ReportDownload/Download.aspx?q=k471B%2fhtf62jwhaelHhu0EqMSfWCvWSpOOBRu76%2bUC%2bgATLEobf%2bMYiVKX0CBOr52d95ViPXJeKbvAbnb%2bSK%2bGumYlSYQT80kTtt5waa5z%2fmbeXT%2fPFqde95DFR1%2b4yQgekl5T6gKipbMFcQJOn5aGYmtI1ALcREIwJRA%2bi%2b3jOE55Cl69TAzBOUWvB73NAKX6S0Y7zF%2bERnSu7TJnJfmqHopWihGtkeMzoqqwsJVgVDEKz84RrPPaDOs2pxg3qE%2bLSrEwu2cpa7bP%2f9t%2fjUVtIgiZMbMjzSf73VnAUSpYNz`

When I go to that URL, its starts to download a zip file that once unzipped, does contain the XML that I need to parse to report to users of the web app I'm creating.

My question is - What is the best way to get at that XML consistently within the app?  This really seems like an arduous approach for the app to take considering all the above would have to take place every time a user loads the Bing page, or changes the date range, but they tell me its the only way to do it.

The path I've been heading down is to get the report with HTTParty and then unzip with RubyZip (have been unsuccessful because of undefined conversion error issues) but I'm unsure what to do from there.  Store in a database (maybe temporarily)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no better way to use the API, cache the results (in your db or on the filesystem) and refresh the data using a rake task that will run periodically. If you do this, consider adding an option for the user to request an immediate refresh.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I assume you mean cache the results of the zip file right?  Can you suggest a good way of downloading/unzipping this file?

Answer (score 0):

Use a background task to download the zip file and then process it, something like delayed_job or resque could be used to start the job with the URL.